php/phpmyadmin GONE after upgrading ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04
I was hoping to get some help with an in-place upgrade for Ubuntu LTS 20.04 to 22.04. This server has a LAMP stack running apache2 2.4.41 mySQL 8.0.39 and php 7.4.3. When I ran the do-release-upgrade command, the upgrade worked however I ran into a few errors about "Since you are removing phpmyadmin ... please choose whether database removal and privilege revocation should be handled with dbconfig-common". But I did not choose to remove phpmyadmin. My site will not start and php is no longer installed, as well as any modules phpmyadmin etc.
This server is a virtual machine, and I reverted back to a know-good snapshot back on Ubutu 20.04 so everything is working now.
Is there anything I can do for this server so that mysql and php will survive the upgrade, so I can try again? Or can I do something after the in-place upgrade to restore php to a working version around 8.x?
